# Flow definition for one of object properties

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flowtype

I have a method that can have one of two parameters to define if some features are enabled or disabled

```
type Params = Enabled | Disabled
```

Where `Enabled` and `Disabled` are type definition like

```
type Disabled = {| 
    config?: string,
    flags?: Array<string> | string
|}

type Enabled = {|
   url?: string,
   flags?: Array<string> | string
|}
```

How can annotate that if the function receive one of the type, can only accept one of the properties? Let's say

```
myWeirdFunction({ config: 'bar', flags: 'foo' })
```

should not be accepted because only one of those properties can be used?

Comment: I don't understand the question. *"because only one of those properties can be used"* Why? That sentence doesn't make sense to me. (also, please read tag descriptions ([tag:flow])).

Comment: So if the function is enabled, you want to accept an url, and if the function is disabled, you want to accept a config?

Comment: If you do `myWeirdFunction({ flags: 'foo' })`, is it enabled or disabled? Your examples overlap, so it seems like it would be impossible to differentiate between the two cases accurately.